# Can I get back an IP previously assigned by my ISP?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I use an Azure SQL server for work (I'm a web developer). Its firewall uses an IP whitelist. I was in the middle of earning extra brownie points over the weekend when my ISP suddenly decided to change my IP on me (which happens a lot :@)!

I know it's an incredibly-long shot, but is there any way to get back the IP that I last had, which Azure thinks is perfectly safe to send data to?

If it's not obvious, I have no control over the firewall whitelist, only my tech lead does. He won't be willing to help until Monday, but I was on a roll and **really** want to get this issue fixed before then.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Not unless you drop and renew your address lease and somehow manage to pull the same address you had.  Otherwise, contact your ISP and see if you can get a reserved or static address.

Comment: Yeah thought so. Thanks :-)

Comment: I believe azure Firewalls now allow you to create rules based on DNS names, so if you can confirm that is the case, you could get a DDNS domain, and allow it. combined with some software on your local network, you can detect changes to your public IP, and update the DNS pointers on your DDNS host so that the DNS IP changes whenever your ISP public IP does. it won't work for a lot of CGNAT scenarios where your IP is constantly changing in realtime, but if you keep it for at least a day or two every time it chagnes, that should work.

Comment: @FrankThomas Nice, this seems like a potential solution. Would a noip.com DDNS work? I don't see why not, but just thought I'd ask. Anyway, write up your comment as an answer and I'll happily accept it :D TYVM!

Comment: My recommendation is that you find a device on your network with DDNS support, and look at the hosts it works with. not every device will work with every host, so start with what you can support with what you have. but yeah no-ip is a well know DDNS host, so it may be a good fit if you  have software that can work with it OOB. let us know how it works, and I'll submit an answer if and when you  have it working.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas, although your last comment is a little confusing. You make it sound much more complicated than No-IP do...it seems as though all I have to do is setup a hostname through their admin panel, download their dynamic update client and set it up with my account info. Am I missing something? EDIT - Oh I just realised that I'd have to set up port forwarding in my router too. And in Azure, setup the firewall rule with the hostname. What else?

Comment: I've not used No-IP personally (My domains are registered with another provider) but from what you say, it sounds like they provide you the software that will detect IP changes and updates their service. In my case, my LAN gateway router supports DDNS for my provider, so instead of installing something, I just told my router who is hosting my domain, what the FQDN is, and provide credentials to use when updating the records. My NAS supports simmilar features. so if running their client software on one of your devices works for you, then it should fit the bill.

Comment: I'm not sure you really need to port forward, though I've not used their software, so I'm not informed on how it functions. would surprise me though. I encourage you to follow their instructions. And first things first, confirm that Azure Firewall will accept the rule you want to use. Azure is a complex beast and sometimes features arrive for one product before another, so I'd start there before you spend any money.

Comment: The port forwarding would be so that I could type myhostname.com in the browser and get my local dev server. No-IP is free so no worries there :D But yes, I should check whether our Azure server actually supports the hostname firewall rule. If so, on-router config. would be super-convenient if my router supported it, but I don't believe it does. I have another OpenWRT one but stopped using it due to other issues. Maybe I should go back to it...anyway sorry for boring you and everyone else LOL. Have a great day mate and thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

The Support of the brownie points network can perhaps credit your
new IP with your old  points, otherwise they are lost.

To avoid your IP changing in the future, requires getting a static IP
from your ISP, which might require extra payment.

Comment: Yeah I doubt I could even get a static IP with this crappy mobile broadband modem, but I might try calling them in the morning (it's 1:30 am on Saturday here). What's this "Azure points" thing (sorry I'm relatively new to Azure)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what are brownie points, but googled that now. I fixed my answer.

Comment: LMAO OK nice one ;-)